# Vue3 vue-intersect not working with v-if?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, intersection-observer

When I use

```
<intersect v-if="activated == true" @enter=" addImages();" > <div class="h-1 w-full border"></div> </intersect>
```

The intersect appears in the dom when the condition is met, but the intersect is not doing any method anymore when I scroll to it.
If I remove the if then I have the problem that with a big screen when the page loads, the intersect gets activated a couple of times while loading.

How to make the intersect work with v-if? what is the reason that its not working?

Here the code of the intersect component ( from this project [vue-intersect](https://github.com/heavyy/vue-intersect)):

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const warn = (msg) => {
  if (!Vue.config.silent) {
    console.warn(msg)
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'intersect',
  abstract: true,
  props: {
    threshold: {
      type: Array,
      required: false,
      default: () => [0, 0.2]
    },
    root: {
      type: typeof HTMLElement !== 'undefined' ? HTMLElement : Object,
      required: false,
      default: () => null
    },
    rootMargin: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: () => '0px 0px 0px 0px'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      if (!entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        this.$emit('leave', [entries[0]])
      } else {
        this.$emit('enter', [entries[0]])
      }

      this.$emit('change', [entries[0]])
    }, {
      threshold: this.threshold,
      root: this.root,
      rootMargin: this.rootMargin
    })

    this.$nextTick(() => {
      if (this.$slots.default && this.$slots.default.length > 1) {
        warn('[VueIntersect] You may only wrap one element in a <intersect> component.')
      } else if (!this.$slots.default || this.$slots.default.length < 1) {
        warn('[VueIntersect] You must have one child inside a <intersect> component.')
        return
      }

      this.observer.observe(this.$slots.default[0].elm)
    })
  },
  destroyed () {
    this.$emit('destroyed')
    this.observer.disconnect()
  },
  render () {
    return this.$slots.default ? this.$slots.default[0] : null
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code of the intersect component

Comment: Edited my previous post and added the code of the component.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're installing the old version of this component which is not compatible with Vue 3, try to uninstall the installed version and install the [next one](https://github.com/heavyy/vue-intersect/tree/next)

```
npm uninstall vue-intersect --save
```

then

```
npm install vue-intersect@next --save
```

Comment: still the same issue. the intersect does nothing with v-if-